# Reuse menuBarTemplate across views

Tags: tvos, tvml

I'm trying to create a simple TVML based app for tvOS. I'm having a problem to wrap my head around how the templating of the menu bar is supposed to work.

Let's assume my `tab1.tvml` looks like this:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/tvml/layout_elements/menubar

And I have one other template called `tab2.tvml` that only has the text "Hello World" in it. When I start my app tab1.tvml is correctly shown with the menu bar. With my actionHandler it's also switching to `tab2.tvml` if I select it in the menu bar.

Simplified version of my action handler:

```
function handleMenuBarEvents(event) {
  var doc = resourceLoader.getDocument("tab2.tvml");
  navigationDocument.pushDocument(doc);
}
```

But the question is:

How do I "inherit" the menu bar so it's shown on all views when I swipe down like it's in other tvOS apps? Do I have to copy my menu bar into all views and update them everywhere if I decide to add a new menu tab?

Thanks!